# How to delete objects and their historical records at once in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an object called PTORequest which have a history field for storing HistoricalRecords of it.

```
history = HistoricalRecords()
```

I have not mentioned `cascade_delete_history=True` while creating history column which would automatically cascade history records.

How do I delete all the objects and their historical records from PTORequest table without doing model changes and migrations?

One thing I can think of is this:

```
for i in PTORequest.objects.all():
    print i.history.all().delete()
    print i.delete()
```

Is there any other efficient way to do this?

I'm using **Django 1.11**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all object historical records by [Querying history on model class](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/1.8.2/usage.html#querying-history-on-a-model-class)

So something like this:

```
PTORequest.history.all().delete()
```